# Android webview using javascript to make footer sit at the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, android, webview, footer

This may not be an issue for many people but it took me ages to work out the solution which, inevitably, was glaringly obvious once I knew how to tackle it. So in order to help others in the same boat I am going to ask and answer this question.

Basically I had several html pages that differed in height and it was not always obvious if scrolling was required or if what was visible on the screen was all that was available on the page.

So, I introduced a green line as a footer that would sit at the bottom of the screen if no scrolling was required but would sit at the bottom of the text if scrolling was required. In other words, if the user was required to scroll then the green line would not be present on the visible portion of the screen.

I cannot believe how difficult this task was proving to be.

Initially I just have a green line at the bottom of the text:

```
<div id="footer" style="width: 320px; height: 5px; background:#fff url(./images/body_bg.gif) repeat-x;"></div>
```

But this sometimes meant that for pages with one or two lines of text had the footer sitting nearly at the top of the screen. This was not acceptable so I introduced

```
style="position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%; "
```

to the container div and

```
<div id="footer" style="width: 320px; height: 5px; background:#fff url(./images/body_bg.gif) repeat-x; position:relative; bottom:0;"></div>
```

Added the position:relative; bottom:0; to the footer and this made the footer sit at the bottom of the screen.

The next problem – which turned out to be the most difficult to overcome – was to make the footer sit beneath all the text if the content was more than the height of the screen. Up until this point the footer would appear at the bottom of the screen even if there was more content below. This meant that the user again never knew if there was more content to be read.

So to overcome this issue I used some javascript that was called when the page loaded

```
function getDocHeight(){
            var documentBody = document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetHeight;
            var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

            if(documentBody<windowHeight){
                document.getElementById('footer').style.position="absolute";
                document.getElementById('footer').style.bottom="0";
            }
        }
```

This compared the window height to the height of the wrapper container if the window height was greater than the wrapper container then make the footer sit at the bottom of the screen. Otherwise, have it sit below the last line of text.

The key was to introduce a wrapper div  whose sole purpose was to know its own height for the if condition to be possible.

Comment: Oh forgot to say, for this solution to work I had to change the position:absolute to position:relative       <div id="footer" style="width: 320px; height: 5px; background:#fff url(./images/body_bg.gif) repeat-x; position:relative; bottom:0;"></div>

Comment: Interesting. I achieved a bottom footer on my website by using a custom touchscreen scroll feature and placing the site content in a inner, scrollable div :) It doesn't have that green bar effect however, which is an interesting idea.